# I keep getting this error Instance method 'background(_:ignoresSafeAreaEdges:)' requires that 'String' conform to 'ShapeStyle'

Tags: swift, swiftui

I'm not very experienced with swift and am trying to make an app. I've tried playing around with the error and searching the internet but I can't find a solution. ***Also note I'm running Xcode 14 beta 3***

**Here's the error,**
it occurs on line 40 (line start ".padding(.vertical)")

> Instance method 'background(_:ignoresSafeAreaEdges:)' requires that
> 'String' conform to 'ShapeStyle'

**here's the code,**

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("text")
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing], 15.0)
            
            Image("Customise")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
            
            Text("xkdlvlx")
                .font(.title2)
                .fontWeight(.heavy)
                .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                .padding([.top, .leading, .trailing], 15.0)
            
            Image("Customise")
                .resizable()
                .scaledToFit()
        }
        .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
            Button("Hello"){
                
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .padding(.vertical)
            .background("StickyButtonBackground")
        }
    }
    
    struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
        static var previews: some View {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What is it that you are trying to achieve? You can't set a `String` as a background for a view, `background` requires a `View`.

Comment: have a look at this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/background(_:ignoressafeareaedges:)  it gives you the answer to your question. I recommend your search the net for more than just 5-10 seconds.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I have tried that but I still don't understand.

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine I have been searching for a day now not 5 seconds  and I found that documentation yesterday but didn't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this here

```
        .background("StickyButtonBackground")
```

I assume it might be either color or image from Assets catalog, like

```
        .background(Color("StickyButtonBackground"))
        .background(Image("StickyButtonBackground"))
```